# Passing Variable Through a Page into a script

Tags: php, json, variables, maps

OK, Here is my problem.  I have a few pages that display points on a map. These points correspond to lat and long in a database of photos that have been uploaded for work that was completed by my employees. 
I want to display only the points that correspond to a specific work order.  Here is what i have.
This is My Index.php file

```
<?php include 'active.php';
$work_order = $_REQUEST['work_order'];
global $work_order;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Work Order GPS Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font: normal 14px Verdana; }
        h1 { font-size: 24px; }
        h2 { font-size: 18px; }
        #sidebar { float: right; width: 30%; }
        #main { padding-right: 15px; }
        .infoWindow { width: 220px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
}
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        callback(request);
    }
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
}     
    var map;

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(38.988297, -75.785499);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function init() {

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: center,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

makeRequest('get_locations.php?work_order=$work_order', function(data) {

    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        displayLocation(data[i]);
    }
});
}

function displayLocation(location) {

var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'  + location.name +     '</strong>'
                + '<br/>'     + location.date_time
                + '<br/>'     + location.work_order + '</div>';

if (parseInt(location.lat) == 0) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: location.name
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }
    });
} else {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lon));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: position,
        title: location.name
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
}


    </script>
</head>
<center>
<body onload="init();">

    <h1>Work Order GPS Data</h1>

    <section id="sidebar">
        <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 95%; height: 840px;"></div>
    </section>

</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Then i have my get_locations.php

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
$work_order = $_REQUEST['work_order'];

try {

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    if($work_order != ''){ 
    $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM exif WHERE work_order=$work_order");
    }else{$sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM exif");
    }
    $locations = $sth->fetchAll();

    echo json_encode( $locations );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My problem is that when i go to http://work.newmansecurity.com/gps/?work_order=1234 i am not only getting points for work order 1234 i am getting all of them. However if i go directly to /gps/get_locations.php?work_order=1234 it works.  So some reason the variable is not getting passed as i wish.

Please HELP

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*****SOLVED*****

Changed the

```
function init() {

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: center,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

makeRequest(<?php echo json_encode($url); ?>, function(data) {

    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        displayLocation(data[i]);
    }
});
}
```

To this.  Using json encode to pass the variable.  Works Great

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your variable $work_order in your query with single quotes.

Comment: my get_locations.php works fine. So i don't believe it is an issue here.  My problem lies in getting the variable from one page to another.  I believe it is in the          makeRequest('get_locations.php?work_order=$work_order', function(data)    section but im not sure.